# flutter Dart Sticky Header from Json

Tags: dart, flutter

i am trying to create flutter sticky header list from json. i am finding it difficult to group by date from json i like to understand more about how to manupluate list and maps. if any body can help.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5bbe598c20a312e8f3a51692",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "853882bb-5432-4efa-9886-38491397cb22",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$3,493.46",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 22,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Maryellen",
      "last": "Moody"
    },
    "company": "SURETECH",
    "registered": "Fri Jul 21 1995 05:54:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bbe598c325e76f346816167",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "672ac480-f8fc-47e8-a960-bac230f11dab",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,081.07",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 39,
    "eyeColor": "green",
    "name": {
      "first": "Duffy",
      "last": "Knight"
    },
    "company": "CYCLONICA",
    "registered": "Fri Jul 21 1995 09:54:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bbe598c0ce158b98ebafcf2",
    "index": 2,
    "guid": "4528d59a-2eb1-4726-ae4b-5cc8d9495d5e",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$2,588.97",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 29,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": {
      "first": "Traci",
      "last": "Grimes"
    },
    "company": "DOGNOST",
    "registered": "Sun Jul 31 2011 03:25:47 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5bbe598cc666e2e9561ad82e",
    "index": 3,
    "guid": "085883af-3ad4-4779-ac4d-5c5374d81144",
    "isActive": true,
    "balance": "$3,928.99",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 26,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": {
      "first": "Reyna",
      "last": "Bond"
    },
    "company": "MOREGANIC",
    "registered": "Sun Jul 31 2011 06:25:47 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
  }
]
```

i am trying to get records for same date and group them with sticky header

### Fri Jul 21 1995 - sticky header

$3,493.46 - Maryellen
$3,081.07 - Duffy

### Sun Jul 31 2011

$2,588.97 - Traci
$3,928.99 - Reyna

packages i am trying to impliment 
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sticky_header_list
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sticky_headers

i am new to flutter. but i am in love with it. trying to undersand logics

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. load json and convert to data object
2. group data object by date
3. convert group data into views

Check the following codes, it should work as your expected.

```
// main.dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:sticky_headers/sticky_headers.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or press Run > Flutter Hot Reload in IntelliJ). Notice that the
        // counter didn't reset back to zero; the application is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CompanyPage(title: "Company Page")
    );
  }
}

class Name {
  final String first;
  final String last;
  Name({this.first, this.last});

  Name.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : first = json['first'],
        last = json['last'];
}

class Company {
  final String id;
  final int index;
  final String guid;
  final bool isActive;
  final String balance;
  final String picture;
  final int age;
  final String eyeColor;
  final Name name;
  final String company;
  final DateTime registered;

  Company({
    this.id, this.index, this.guid, this.isActive,
    this.balance, this.picture, this.age, this.eyeColor,
    this.name, this.company, this.registered
  });

  Company.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id          = json['_id'],
        index       = json['index'],
        guid        = json['guid'],
        isActive    = json['isActive'],
        balance     = json['balance'],
        picture     = json['picture'],
        age         = json['age'],
        eyeColor    = json['eyeColor'],
        name        = Name.fromJson(json['name']),
        company     = json['company'],
        registered  = _toDateTime(json['registered']);

  /// Fri Jul 21 1995 05:54:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)
  static DateTime _toDateTime(String dateTime) {
    return DateFormat("EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss").parseUtc(dateTime);
  }
}

class CompanyViewInfo {
  final Widget header;
  final Widget child;
  CompanyViewInfo({this.header, this.child});
}

class CompanyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  CompanyPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CompanyPageState();
}

class _CompanyPageState extends State<CompanyPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _getCompanyList(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
              if (snapshot.data == null) return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

              final groupList = _groupByDate(snapshot.data);
              return ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                    StickyHeader(
                        header: groupList[index].header,
                        content: groupList[index].child
                    ),
                itemCount: groupList.length,
              );
            })
    );
  }
}

Future<List<Company>> _getCompanyList() async {
  final jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/companies.json");
  return List.castFrom(json.decode(jsonString)).map((c) => Company.fromJson(c)).toList();
}

List<CompanyViewInfo> _groupByDate(List<Company> companyList) {
  final map = groupBy(
      keySelector: (Company c) => DateFormat("EEE MM d yyyy").format(c.registered),
      list: companyList
  );

  return toList(
      mapF: (String date, List<Company> list) {
        final header = Container(
          height: 50.0,
          color: Colors.blue[700],
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Text(date, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        );

        final child = Text(list.map((c) => "${c.balance} - ${c.name.first}").join(" "));

        return CompanyViewInfo(header: header, child: child);
      },
      map: map
  );
}

Map<K, List<T>> groupBy<T, K>({K Function(T) keySelector, List<T> list}) {
  Map<K, List<T>> destination = Map();

  for (T element in list) {
    final key = keySelector(element);
    final value = destination[key] ?? List();
    value.add(element);
    destination[key] = value;
  }

  return destination;
}

List<R> toList<K, V, R>({R Function(K, V) mapF, Map<K, V> map}) {
  List<R> destination = List();
  map.forEach((k, v) => destination.add(mapF(k, v)));
  return destination;
}
```

in `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.15.7
  sticky_headers: "^0.1.7"

assets:
  - assets/companies.json
```

remember to put `companies.json` on `your_project_root/assets/companies.json`

Comment: Couldn't find any output